# BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead -> nBlockUse) error

Tags: c++

I'm going to write a program that using virtual function to do a polygon calculation, but after I finish the program, there are BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead -> nBlockUse)  error

```
// pointers to base class
#include <iostream>
#include "Polygon.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "Triangle.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
Rectangle rect1(4, 5);
Rectangle rect2(3, 3);
Triangle tri(4, 4, false);
int triLength[3] = { 5, 4, 3 };
tri.setsideLength(triLength);

Polygon * p = &rect1;
cout << "Rectangle 1: " << endl;
cout << "\tArea: " << p->area() << endl;
cout << "\tSide: ";
p->printsideLength();
rect1.printsideLength();
cout << "\tTotal Side Length: " << p->totalsideLength() << endl;
p = &rect2;
cout << "Rectangle 2: " << endl;
cout << "\tArea: " << p->area() << endl;
cout << "\tSide: ";
p->printsideLength(); 
rect2.printsideLength();
cout << "\tTotal Side Length: " << p->totalsideLength() << endl;
p = &tri;
cout << "Triangle: " << endl;
cout << "\tArea: " << p->area() << endl;
cout << "\tSide: ";
p->printsideLength(); 
cout << "\tTotal Side Length: " << p->totalsideLength() << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Here is the main.cpp of the program, the program no need to input any thing just need to show the result of it.

Here are the three class(cpp&h)

```
#ifndef Polygon_H
#define Polygon_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Polygon{
private:
int noOfSide;
bool isAllSideEqual;
int* sideLength;
public:
Polygon();
Polygon(int n,bool s);
~Polygon();
void setsideLength(int* sl);
void printsideLength();
int totalsideLength();
virtual int area();
};

#endif
```

.

```
#include "Polygon.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Polygon::Polygon(){
    noOfSide = 3;
    isAllSideEqual = false;
    sideLength = new int[noOfSide];
    sideLength = &sideLength[noOfSide];
};


Polygon::Polygon(int n,bool s){
    if (n<3)
    {
        noOfSide = 3;
        isAllSideEqual = false;}
    else
    {
        noOfSide = n;
        isAllSideEqual = s;
    };
    sideLength = new int[noOfSide];
    sideLength = &sideLength[noOfSide];

};

Polygon::~Polygon(){
    delete[] sideLength;
};


void Polygon::setsideLength(int* sl){
    for(int i=0;i<noOfSide;i++)
        sideLength[i] = sl[i];
};
void Polygon::printsideLength(){
    for(int i=0;i<noOfSide;i++)
        cout << sideLength[i] <<" ";
};

int Polygon::totalsideLength(){
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<noOfSide;i++)
        total += sideLength[i];
    return total;
};
int Polygon::area(){
    return 0;
};

   #ifndef Triangle_H
   #define Triangle_H

  #include <iostream>
  #include "Polygon.h"
  using namespace std;

class Triangle:public Polygon
{
private:
    int width;
    int height;
public:
    Triangle(int w,int h,bool s);
    virtual int area();
};
#endif


 #include "Triangle.h"
 #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
 Triangle::Triangle(int w,int h,bool s){
    width = w;
    height = h;
    Polygon(3,s);
};

int Triangle::area(){
    int total = 0;
    total = (width*height)/2;
    return total;
};


  #ifndef Rectangle_H
  #define Rectangle_H

  #include <iostream>
  #include "Polygon.h"
  using namespace std;

  class Rectangle:public Polygon{
  private:
  int width;
  int height;
 public:
  Rectangle(int w,int h);
  void printsideLength();
  virtual int area();
 };
 #endif

#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Rectangle::Rectangle(int w,int h){
    width=w;
    height=h;
    if(width = height)
        Polygon(4,true);
    else
        Polygon(4,false);
    int* size =new int[4];
    size[0] = width;
    size[1] = height;
    size[2] = width;
    size[3] = height;
    Polygon::setsideLength(size);
};

void Rectangle::printsideLength(){
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        cout<< width<<" "<<height <<" ";
};

int Rectangle::area(){
    int total =0;
    total = width*height;
    return total;
};
```

The program is without any compilation error, so the only problem is about the memory
but where is it wrong? is the virtual function part wrong or any other part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems.

In your `Polygon` constructors, the second line in

```
sideLength = new int[noOfSide];
sideLength = &sideLength[noOfSide];
```

is the main bug.
It makes `sideLength` point past the end of the memory you just allocated.
Using this pointer is undefined.
You're both copying to that location later and passing it to `delete`, which are both invalid.
You only need `sideLength = new int[noOfSide];`.
You also need a proper copy constructor and assignment operator since the class is manually managing memory.

(What you *really* should do is use `std::vector<int>` and stop worrying about memory allocation.)

In your subclass constructors, `Polygon(3,s);` and the like don't initialise your base class, they create an unnamed `Polygon` which is immediately discarded.

You should initialise the base class in the initialiser list (along with your other members):

```
Triangle::Triangle(int w, int h, bool s)
  : Polygon(3, s),
    width(w),
    height(h)
{
}
```

`Rectangle`'s constructor has the same issue, with the added problem of your using assignment, `=`, where you should use equality, `==`.
(Your compiler can warn you about this if you enable its warnings. Do that, and listen to them.)

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(int w, int h)
   : Polygon(4, w == h),
     width(w),
     height(h)
{
    int size[] = {width, height, width, height};
    setsideLength(size);
}
```

Comment: for the sidelength part, the program is need create a dynamic integer array with the size equals to the number of sides and store the address of the array to the pointer sideLength.

Comment: to satisfy this requirement, should I just create a new array and then assign the address to sideLength? like int* array = new int[noOfSide]; sideLength = &array?

Comment: @TomFong "create a new array and then assign the address to sideLength" is exactly what `sideLength = new int[noOfSide];` does and that is what you should do.

Comment: does it mean that when I create a dynamic array, the pointer will store the address of it, and the content of the all will be NULL or the address of the array?